# USB device not removable

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive

I'm facing a problem regarding my USB flash device. Somehow, my USB Flash Device is not recognized as a removable device, it's now a partition of a hard disk drive device now. Even though I go to a different system it's not recognizable at all.

Comment: Did you try to use the Disk Utility in Ubuntu to remove partitions of your flash disk? then create a simple FAT partition

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use Disks to reformat the drive to the FAT file format, used on most USB sticks.

First, open Disks. You should see something like this:

[image: The Disks window, showing a HDD, a CD Drive, and a USB Stick.]

The bottom-most one is what we'll be working with. Click the gears underneath the Volumes panel and click "Format." You'll be greeted with another window asking you for options. Select these settings:

[image: Erase all data, format to FAT, insert your own label.]

You can set the label to whatever you want, but this will erase anything on that drive, and reformat it to FAT.

Comment: Can you provide directions on how to do that?

Comment: I am not at my Ubuntu computer right now, nor will I be till 4 PM EDT. I'll edit my answer then!

Comment: Done! A bit later than I wanted to, but GTA V doesn't play itself! ^^"